# Unitary matrix in form of Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrices

Is there way to prove that every unitary matrix $A$ can be expressed in form of a Hermitian matrix $H$ such that eigenvalue of A is not 1?

I know that the form is $A=(I-iH)(I+iH)^{-1}$
And $A$ can be proved to be unitary by taking transjugate of $A$. 
But can this form be arrived starting from $A$?

Comment: Your identity does not hold for $A= I$

Comment: I think you mean $(I-i H)(I+i H)^{-1}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It came as is in one of the previous year papers of an exam. But clearly there seems to be an error. I will edit it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To show that every unitary matrix can be expressed in this form, it suffices to make the following observations:

- A unitary matrix is determined completely by its eigenvalues
- $H$ may take any set of real numbers as its eigenvalues
- For every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $H$, $\frac{1 - i\lambda}{1 + i \lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$
- The map $\lambda \in \Bbb R \mapsto \frac{1 - i\lambda}{1 + i \lambda}$ has, as its image, the entirety of the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: I know how to prove the identity. I need help with proving every unitary matrix can be expressed in this form

Comment: Excuse me, I'll edit accordingly

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot!